# How to match line in fstab file

Tags: text-processing, grep

we have the following line in `/etc/fstab` file

```
/dev/mapper/vg_D /data/container xfs     defaults        0 0
```

but when we try to match the line as

```
LINE=/data/container

grep -qxF "$LINE" /etc/fstab || echo "line not in file !!!"
line not in line !!!
```

seems that  `grep -qxF` not match the line `/data/container`

where we are wrong? and how to match the line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the `-x` parameter, it tries to match entire line

```
       -x, --line-regexp
              Select only those matches that exactly match the whole  line.   For  a  regular  expression
              pattern, this is like parenthesizing the pattern and then surrounding it with ^ and $.
```

so it would match only a line containing only `/data/container` and nothing else.

Comment: Removing `-x` is a step in the right direction but you still need to add `-w` or similar to avoid partial matches (e.g. `/data/container` matching `/data/containershipment`) and then you still have to figure out how to make `/data/container` match only on the 2nd space-separated field instead of anywhere on the line while also ensuring any regexp metachars in it are treated literally. It's quite a puzzle trying to make grep do this job robustly!

Answer (score 3):

You should be using awk instead of grep for robustness as your current grep approach even when partially fixed to get rid of the `-x` and even if you fixed it further by adding `-w` will STILL produce false matches. Replace your grep command with this:

```
awk -v line="$LINE" '$2==line{exit 1}' /etc/fstab
```

or even better just do the printing from within awk:

```
awk -v line="$LINE" '
    $2==line { f=1; exit }
    END { print (f ? "line inf file" : "line not in file"); exit !f }
' /etc/fstab
```

If `"$LINE"` can contain backslashes then use:

```
line="$LINE" awk '$2==ENVIRON["line"]...'
```

instead of setting `line` with `-v` so awk doesn't convert `\t` into a tab, for example.